# orchaRd::i2_ml with advised number of boot (1000): Optimizer (nlminb) did not achieve convergence

Tags: metafor

I ran this model without any problem:

```
model = rma.mv(r ~ 1, V=Vr,
data = Data_intra_birds,
random = c(~ 1 | STUDY_ID.1,~ 1 | INDEX, ~ 1 | TREE_T),
R = list(TREE_T = forcedC_intra_birds),
method = "REML")
```

Then, I used the i2_ml function from the orchaRd R package to calculate total heterogeneity and the heterogeneity derived from each random effect, using the advised number of bootstrapping to obtain CI:

```
orchaRd::i2_ml(model, data=Data_intra_birds, boot=1000)
```

but an error shows up:

Bootstrapping [===>---------------------------------------------------------------------------]   5% ETA: 30mError: Optimizer (nlminb) did not achieve convergence (convergence = 1).

I have tried different values for bootstrapping and it only runs well when I have lower values like 10 or 20. However, these values don't allow for a good estimative of CI.